# How to encrypt data with the private key stored in AndroidKeyStore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, rsa

I am making an Android application that needs to communicate with a server. I want to use RSA to encrypt data but I face some problems with encryption.

This is how the process goes:

1. Generated public key and private key on the Android Client and stored them in AndroidKeyStore.
2. Private key is used to encrypt data, and the public key will be shared with the server.
3. Server will decrypt data with the public key.

However, I don't know how to get the private key from AndroidKeyStore and decrypt data.

I have searched for google but what I got is just encrypt data with the public key and decrypt data with the private key or just using AES.

It may be a simple question but I am sorry that I am not familiar with the AES decryption in Android or Java. So I will be happy if there are some explanations. I am using Kotlin but you can also just give me an answer in Java.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Google results are correct: the encryption in public-key cryptography (like RSA) is done with the public key (of the recipient), the decryption with the own private key, s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). This makes it necessary to exchange the public keys before communication. Your way does not make sense in the context of confidentiality, since anyone (with the public key) could decrypt the message. By the way, in the context of signing, you sign with the private key and verify with the public key.

Comment: Thanks. I just wants to make sure only the client can send the message.

Comment: *I am making an Android application that needs to communicate with a server*. Then almost certainly you should be using HTTPS.